# CPP - using * or & to return address

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, pointers, visual-c++, reference

I am writing  a code to make a linked list.
one of the function I wrote in order to make a linked list easier in the main function was[node is the name of a struct conatains a.data b.pointer name next) :

```
    node& create_node(int value)
    {
    node newitem;
    newitem.data=value;
    newitem.next=NULL;
    return (newitem);
    };
```

When I write the function like this everything is ok but I want to write the function header as :

```
    node * create_node(int value)
```

But when I write it that way and I write

```
  return *newitem;
```

I get an error.
I wanted to ask why the VS shows me an error in the 2nd way and what is the difference between using * and & [I already read here about references but I don't understand why one should use it in functions as , from what I understood using references takes additional space and not contributing ] .

edit :thank you for help, when I posted this  it was before I even ran a test on the main function only tried to avoid mistakes before compilation .
It took me some time but now I see the fundamental mistake I did .

Comment: Your first function is not correct.  You are returning a reference to a local object that will be destroyed once the function ends.  You should also take a look at this: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/42958/linkedlist-with-node-implementation

Comment: @NathanOliver I should have duped it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Comment: 'When I write the function like this everything is ok ' - besides a warning you should not ignore - your code is fundamental broken.

Comment: I think you should read [What are the differences between a pointer variable and a reference variable in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in).

Answer (score 4):

Your code returns a reference to a variable.

Unfortunately you return a reference to a local variable.  This will fail, because the local variable will be destroyed uppont returning, but the caller will still try to reference it (that's UB) !

So if you want to return a reference, you shall make sure the object still exist:

```
node& create_node(int value) { 
    node* newitem = new node;
    newitem->data=value;
    newitem->next=NULL;
    return (*newitem);  // return the objet: this will be then be converted to a reference
}
```

You could also work with pointers as suggested by another answer.  However in this case, I'd opt for `shared_ptr`:

```
shared_ptr<node> create_node(int value) { 
    node* newitem = new node;
    newitem->data=value;
    newitem->next=NULL;
    return (shared_ptr<node>(newitem)); 
}
```

Comment: Is defining "shared_ptr" at the "return" good practice? Should we separate variable declaring and defining?

Comment: @CloudCho interesting. Can you develop your question? I did not get what would be wrong here

Comment: Would it be a problem in failure of memory allocation? I put my question at https://stackoverflow.com/q/77695290/5595995.

Comment: @CloudCho I think you have already some valuable answers for the question there. Indeed, my suggestion should not be taken out of context: it was based on the existing UB code of OP, helping for an easy fix for correcting UB and then suggesting a transition to shared ptr, which apparently was not known by OP. Indeed, would I have written it from scratch, I would have use make_shared natively to avoid leaking issues, and I would have added a constructor in node to initialize things properly ALlWAYS. Depending on the usage.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return a pointer you should use a pointer:

```
node* create_node(int value)
{
    node *newitem = new node;
    newitem->data = value;
    newitem->next = NULL;
    return newitem;
};
```

Also please consider who'll delete the object then.

Comment: You should not recommend a raw memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

You should return &newitem.

But given the fact that your newitem is only available in this function's scope, the returned pointer will point to a destroyed object, so "nothing", or rather it will result in undefined behavior.

I guess you want your newitem to be created dynamically.

```
node * create_node(int value)
{
    node * newitem = new node;
    newitem->data=value;
    newitem->next=NULL;
    return newitem;
};
```

Comment: You should not recommend a raw memory allocation.

Comment: @szulak "raw memory allocation"...are you mentioning `node * newitem = new node` line? Would you add some explanation?