# function definition in C++

Tags: c++, function

These are (some) of the ways to define a function in C++ (depending on what the function should do):

```
type f_name (type par) {/*...*/}
type f_name(type& par) {/*...*/}
```

where the first one passes as argument a copy of `par` to the function, whereas the second one passes a reference to the variable `par`, which means that if something 'happens' to the variable, it will be reflected in the variable itself.

My confusion is with the following definition

```
type& f_name(type& par) {/*...*/}
```

I don't understand what the `&` means in the return type of the function.
Also when should I and shouldn't I use it?

**EDIT:** I would appreciate if the answer came with a representative example

Comment: It means the same thing as it does for the parameter: the function returns a reference to some object, rather than a copy of that object.

Comment: It's a *return by reference*. It's rare to see in a non-member function as it allows the caller to modify whatever the reference is referring to. It's quite common when overloading operators

Comment: Ok, but passing the variable as a reference effectively achieves that, i.e. that the passing parameter is modified. What does it mean that -on top of the reference to the parameter- the function  returns a reference to any object that returns...?

Comment: One thing to note, returning reference to variable with atomic storage duration from function is UB.

Comment: In general it could happen that the function is updating a particular variable in the global scope including, but not limited to, creating new heap space for it. In this case it makes sense to return an address (or a pointer). You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29309414/cpp-using-or-to-return-address) interesting.

Comment: Also, [this article](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/74a-returning-values-by-value-reference-and-address/) explains the use case difference of return by address and return by reference

Comment: @pvc: Not quite - the reference might also be passed into the function as a parameter. Some of the C++ standard library functions work like this, so I'm not mentioning this just to be picky.

Comment: @Bathsheba, your right, thank you.